# ls output colors for specific files?

Tags: linux, git, ls

Is it possible to assign the ls command's output colors for specific files?
The reason I ask is that for git repositories, I want my tracked files to have different colors from untracked ones. So specifically, I want to take the output of "git ls-files" and give those files a certain color (or make the names bold or whatever).

Comment: Color for `ls` is controlled by the environment setting LS_COLORS: http://blog.twistedcode.org/2008/04/lscolors-explained.html

Comment: @WilliamPursell Note, though, that `LS_COLORS` has no effect at all for `git ls-files` - that's completely different. `git ls-colors`, if it colors at all (which I'm not sure of, although `git status` definitely does), would consult various `config.X` configuration variables to determine coloring. See `git help config` for more information.

Comment: @twalberg To clarify, I don't want to colorize the output of "git ls-file", rather, I want to take the files output *by* "git ls-file" and colorize them when I run plain old "ls". I think I can use Breno's answer though, by basically just constructing an LS_COLORS variable that's very long and essentially specifies each file. I'll report results later.

Comment: That doesn't sound very useful - you'll need to update your LS_COLORS definition every single time any single file in your repository might have changed status... Perhaps writing a script that uses the output of `git ls-files -t` would be more useful...

Comment: Yes, @twalberg, I agree, and that's the plan. But right now I can't seem to add individual files to the LS_COLORS bash variable. When I do, all colors for all files go away. So, I can do: `export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS":*txt=00;32:"` but I cannot do: `export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS":myfile.txt=00;32:"` because all the colors go away.

Comment: The best I can figure out is the following, in bash:  
`gitcolorize() { export toadd=$(echo $(ls | grep -f <(git ls-files 2>/dev/null) | sed 's/^/\*/g' | sed 's/$/=04:/g') | sed 's/\ //g') ; LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS$toadd ; }`. I can then change my cd command or set up an alias that runs this function whenever I cd into a git repository. I think the problem is that bash gets unhappy if there isn't a "*" at the beginning of each entry in LS_COLORS. So it's not a perfect solution, but it's the next best thing.

Answer (score 2):

For a standard ls command, it is quite easy. Let's say you want to show all .mp3 files in a purple color, then run:

```
$ LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:"*mp3=35:"
```

Also, make sure to guarantee that your ls command has the --color option enabled. I usually use something like:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Purple color is "35". The other basic colors are:

```
0   = default colour
1   = bold
4   = underlined
5   = flashing text
7   = reverse field
40  = black background
41  = red background
42  = green background
43  = orange background
44  = blue background
45  = purple background
46  = cyan background
47  = grey background
100 = dark grey background
101 = light red background
102 = light green background
103 = yellow background
104 = light blue background
105 = light purple background
106 = turquoise background
```

Comment: the question is how to colorize specific file names, not the file extension as a whole

Comment: I have tried to apply this for `json` files but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to achieve the exact same thing to use for git directory listings as well.

My solution is to add a hook in Z shell (`add-zsh-hook chpwd git-alias`) that calls the function `git-alias` when I change directories.
The function `git-alias` defines, based on whether it's a git directory, the functionality of `ll`.

```
function git-alias {
    # Let ll depend on the current directory
    if git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Make sure ll has no alias assigned
        alias ll='ls' && unalias ll
        function ll {
            ls $@ -lF|grep --color=never -e '/$' # directories
            ls $@ -lQ|grep -f <(git ls-files -cdmoi --exclude-standard)|sed -e "s/\(.*\) \"\(.*\)\"$/\1 ${fg[dgray]}\2 (ignored)$reset_color/" # ignored
            ls $@ -l|grep --color=never -f <(git ls-files -c 2>/dev/null) # cached
            ls $@ -lQ|grep -f <(git ls-files -m 2>/dev/null)|sed -e "s/\(.*\) \"\(.*\)\"$/\1 ${fg[blue]}✎ \2$reset_color/" # modified
            ls $@ -lQ|grep -f <(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard 2>/dev/null)|sed -e "s/\(.*\) \"\(.*\)\"$/\1 ${fg[blue]}★ \2$reset_color/" # new
            git ls-files -d 2>/dev/null|sed -e "s/^\(.*\)$/Deleted: ${fg[red]}✗ \1$reset_color/" # deleted
        }
    else
        alias ll='ls -lF'
    fi
}
```

This will return something like:

[image: example output]

It is still not perfect (e.g., note the double entry for the file ‘LICENSE’ and the fixed ordering of files and folders), but it's the best I could achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with another approximate solution:

```
tree | sed -f <(git ls-files | awk -F/ '{ print "s/" $NF "/\033[32m\\0\033[0m/" }')
```

It gets the list of all tracked files from git and creates a sed command for each one that wraps the filename in color escape sequences.

There are some deficiencies:

- The coloring is based on the filename not the whole path. If two files in different directories have the same name and one is tracked while the other one is not, both are colored.
- Actually it's even worse because even a part of the filename is colored. If the file `a` is tracked every `a` is colored. This could probably be fixed by matching the whole line in the sed command.
- Directories are not colored (unless they have the same name as a tracked file; see above). This might be improved by using the `--directory` flag of `git ls-files`
- probably more...

I'm using `tree` instead of `ls` which makes the issue with directories less problematic (because I can see if it contains tracked files). But you can use `ls` in the same way of course.